# Multipart don't work with Spring & Jersey

Tags: spring, file-upload, jersey

I'm facing below errors when using jersey's multipart along with spring. These errors will be thrown when starting the application. Did anyone face same issue? What is the solution?

### Code:

```
@Path("/upload")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class FileUploadResource {


        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
                .getLogger(FileUploadResource.class.getName());





        private AttachmentVO wboardContentVO;

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @Autowired
        private AttachmentService attService;

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationConfig config;

        @PermitAll
        @POST
        @Path("{userId}")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
//      public Response uploadFile( @PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId , @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
//              @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition file) {
        public Response uploadFile( FormDataMultiPart form,@PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId) {

             FormDataBodyPart filePart = form.getField("file");
                      ContentDisposition file =  filePart.getContentDisposition();
                      InputStream uploadedInputStream = filePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);

             ExternalUser user = null;
            try {
                user = userService.getUser(userId);
            } catch (UserNotFoundException e1) {
                throw new FileUploadException("File owner is not found.");
            }

                LOG.trace(file.getFileName() + " uploaded! " + file.getSize());


                if (!SupportedFileTypes
                        .isWBSupportedMimeType(file.getType())) {
                            throw new FileUploadException(" File Type is not supported.");

                }
                try {
                    if (file == null) {
                            throw new FileUploadException("File is null.");
                    }
                    wboardContentVO = new AttachmentVO();
                    wboardContentVO.setAttachmentSize(file.getSize());
                    wboardContentVO.setAttachmentStream(uploadedInputStream);
                    wboardContentVO.setTitle(file.getFileName());
                    wboardContentVO.setAttachmentURL(file.getFileName());
                    wboardContentVO.setMimeType(file.getType());
                    wboardContentVO.setOrgFolderPrefix(config.getContentOrgCode());
                    if (wboardContentVO.isImage()) {
                        wboardContentVO.setSecured(false);
                    }
                    wboardContentVO.setGenerateImage(true);
                    ContentManager contentManager = new ContentManager();
                    wboardContentVO.setFileId(contentManager.uploadContent(
                            wboardContentVO, config.getContentOrgCode()));
                    //persist the data in ddatabase
                    wboardContentVO.setAttachmentOID(attService.addAttachment(wboardContentVO, user));

                    if (SupportedFileTypes.isImageMimeType(file.getType())) {

                        AttachmentPagesRequest apr = new AttachmentPagesRequest(wboardContentVO);
                        return Response.ok().entity(apr).build();
                    } 
                } catch (Exception appEx) {
                    LOG.error(
                            "Exception caught while uploading attachment ["
                                    + wboardContentVO.getTitle() + "] - "
                                    + appEx.getMessage() + "]", appEx);
                            throw new FileUploadException("Cannot convert at this time, please try again later.");

                } finally {
                    LOG.debug("Attachment creation completed...");
                }
            return Response.ok().build();
        }

}
```

### Error:

```
Jan 20, 2014 2:49:56 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.emyed.rest.resource.FileUploadResource.uploadFile(com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.emyed.rest.resource.FileUploadResource.uploadFile(com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart,java.lang.String), annotated with POST of resource, class com.emyed.rest.resource.FileUploadResource, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Jan 20, 2014 2:49:56 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet initiate
SEVERE: Exception occurred when intialization
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jan 20, 2014 2:49:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jan 20, 2014 2:49:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Jersey REST Service
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the same issue. Has anyone found a working implementation?

Comment: Same here...Hopefully someone will answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that there is no jar conflicts i.e if you are using `jersey-spring` and `jersey-multipart` make sure that they posses the same version.
2. Make sure you have `springServlet` set in your `web.xml` correctly and it is taking in-it param to read the base packages